# convert multiple columns as single row with appreciated data

Tags: sql-server-2016

See the image below.

The first table is the actual table.

How to get the expected result in the second table using a procedure when I pass `formid` as parameter?

**example:**
*exec procedure 123*

[image]

Comment: It would be easy to assist if you could provide examples in T-SQL (test script) format. However, by any chance is the first table would have "FieldID" as the "FieldName" different all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Hope following **expected result** script help in your case, but you have prepare it for maximum number of fields.

1. Test environment (1 time execution only) as per your scenario:

```
Create table #Temp
(formid int, FieldName varchar(50), value_ varchar (50) )
go

Insert into #Temp
values 
(101, 'FirstName', 'Name 1'),
(101, 'LastName', 'x'),
(101, 'Email', 'Name@s.com'),
(102, 'FirstName', 'Name 1'),
(102, 'Gender', 'M'),
(102, 'Mobile', '9xxxxxx'),
(103, 'DOB', '19900101')
go
```

1. Expected Result

```
Declare @FormID int = 103

Select  max(Case when F_Rn = 1 Then formid end) as formid, 
        max(Case when F_Rn = 1 Then FieldName end) as Field1,
        max(Case when F_Rn = 2 Then FieldName end) as Field2,
        max(Case when F_Rn = 3 Then FieldName end) as Field3,
        max(Case when F_Rn = 4 Then FieldName end) as Field4,
        max(Case when F_Rn = 5 Then FieldName end) as Field5,
        max(Case when F_Rn = 6 Then FieldName end) as Field6
from            (
                select formid, 
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by FieldName) as F_Rn,
                       FieldName,
                       value_
                from #Temp
                where formid = @FormID
                ) as t
go
```

1. Drop Test environment

```
Drop Table #Temp
go
```